# How to get the indexPath of the particular table from multiple table in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-4.1

Hi i m using 2 tables in a single view and want to get the indexpath of the tables. I use
the below code to get the indexpath. but stil categoryId getting effected whatever table i access not the other thing.  Please help...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    if(tableView=categoryTblView)
    {
        categoryId=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"categoryId=%d",categoryId);
    }

    else if(tableView=regionTblView)
    {
        regionId=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"regionId=%d",regionId);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To test equality here, you need to use `==` instead of a single equal sign (which is for assignment).

So the code should be:

```
if (tableView == categoryTblView)
{
    ...
}
else if (tableView == regionTblView)
{
    ...
}
```